# "How much reduction" or "How would reduction"

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-meaning, sentence-structure, auxiliary-verbs

I have a method A, which is used to reduce the computation of difficult models. I would like to say that using this method will provide a great reduction in the computation of the model.

> Method A reduces the computation of the model to the half. Then, we can see how **much** the great reduction of the model computation will be introduced using method A.

or

> Method A reduces the computation of the model to the half. Then, we could see how **would** the great reduction of the model computation will be introduced using method A.

I would like to know, is it correct to use **much** with the word **reduction** or **would**, and why?

Comment: Is this a proofreading question?

Comment: @MichaelRybkin, No, I just need to know is it correct to use "much" or "would" with the word "reduction". As I understand "much" is used with an uncountable noun.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both versions of the passage are awkward.

The phrase *to the half* is unidiomatic as you've used it. Rather than say *to the half*, we generally say *in half*.

I suggest simplifying it into something briefer—which also dispenses with your word choice.

> Method A greatly simplifies the computation of the model, reducing its complexity in half.

---

That aside, there is no reason to have to choose between *much* and *would*.

You can say something like this:

> We can see how **much** of a reduction in the computation of the model **would** be achieved by using method A.

---

Here, *reduction* is uncountable. That does not mean that it's not *measurable*.

Consider this:

> "How **much** flower should I use?"
>   "One cup."

*Flower* here is uncountable. It's a mass noun. But you can still *measure* it.

In the same vein:

> "How **much** of a reduction will it be?"
>   "50 percent."

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But as I understand **much** is only used with uncountable.

Comment: @Maryam I have updated my answer.